# Solving for a function after replacing and substituting in an expression

Tags: equation-solving, functions, replacement, symbols, assignment

I am trying to isolate $X(s)$ in the following expression:

```
e1 = LaplaceTransform[m x''[t] + c x'[t] + k x[t] == HeavisideTheta[t], t, s]
e1 /. LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s] -> X[s]
Solve[e1, X[s]]
```

But Solve returns an empty array. What is wrong here?

Comment: Because you didn't replace anything in `e1`, you did the replacement and displayed its result, but `e1` is unchanged - you didn't _name_ the output of the replacement, so to say. Do `e2 = e1 /. LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s] -> X[s]` and then `Solve[e2, X[s]]`.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.

Comment: Relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/29734.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `e1 /. LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s] -> X[s]` doesn't replace anything **in the expression** `e1`. It makes a substitution/replacement according to some rule and *displays the result*, but `e1` remains unchanged. This might be a bit confusing due to the *replacing* name of the function. But consider  its operator form:

```
`ReplaceAll[rule][expression]`
```

`ReplaceAll[rule]` is an operand acting on `expression`. It has the same structure like every other MMA command, e.g. `Det`: `Det[mat]` computes the determinant of `mat` and displays the result; it does not change `mat` into its determinant, `mat` is unchanged. The same reasoning applies to `ReplaceAll`.

So, if one does

```
e2 = e1 /. LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s] -> X[s]
Solve[e2, X[s]]
```

the result will be

[image]

**NOTE:** In the above I made some general statements for the sake of illustration. However, it's important to emphasize that **there are commands that actually change the expression they act** on, e.g. `AppendTo`. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/22013) for a discussion.